# JS passing variable to .php, php returning based on variable, displayed by javascript, using AJAX and triggers with bind('input', function ()

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i am trying to make a form auto fill some input feilds onchange, i cant seem to figure out how to send the #url feild to my php script, any input or suggestions are very welcome.

```
$('#url').bind('input', function () {});
```

on keychange send the value of input id $url to ajax.php

where this will run with that value

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `inserted_posts` WHERE `search_name` = '$url'";
```

result is echoed back

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

and then displayed in the other input feilds

```
           $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',   
            data: "", 

            dataType: 'json', //data format      
            success: function (data) //on recieve of reply
            {
                var catagoryPHP = data[1]; 
                var imageNamePHP = data[3];

                $('#catagory').html(catagoryPHP);
                $('#imageName').html(imageNamePHP);
            }
            });
```

I cant seem to figure out how to send $URL to the ajax.php and start the chain of events?

All my code

JS:

```
$(function () {
$('#url').bind('input', function () {
    $(this).val() // get  value




    $(function () {
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php', //the script to call to get data          
            data: "", //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
            //for example "id=5&parent=6"
            dataType: 'json', //data format      
            success: function (data) //on recieve of reply
            {
                var catagoryPHP = data[1]; 
                var imageNamePHP = data[3];

                //--------------------------------------------------------------------
                // 3) Update html content
                //--------------------------------------------------------------------
                $('#catagory').html(catagoryPHP);
                $('#imageName').html(imageNamePHP);

            }
        });
    });
});
});
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
require_once ('DBconnect.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM `inserted_posts` WHERE `search_name` = '$url'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // Can be 'GET'
        url: 'ajax.php',      
        data: { url: $('#url').val() },         
        success: function (data) //on recieve of reply
        {
            /* Your code to execute on success of the request */
        }
    });
```

#url will be accessible in your php script as $_POST['url'] or $_GET['url'] depending on which type you put in `type` for the request.

Please remember to sanitize all user input with using prepared statements or `mysqli_escape_string()` functions.

Comment: I seem to be getting a syntax error when i put that ajax request above the other one and between the dettect keystroke function

Comment: Thanks it sends the requests, but im getting false when it is supposed to represent it acording to the console

On keychange it does a POST which works, and then it does a GET to get the results and fill out the other input feilds, but that one results in FALSE, i do see all the correct information returned in the console tho, from the query

and btw thx so much for the help :)